# How do I use the EWDK?

Tags: windows, driver

The Enterprise Windows Driver Development Kit has a stripped-down version of Visual Studio shipped with it. The documentation states one should invoke `MSBuild`. How am I supposed to obtain the Visual Studio project file to invoke it on? Are there any examples detailing the use of the EWDK available?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old question and I'm sure you already answered your own question, but for those who live in the future and are coming across this post, this is how I used the EWDK and msbuild.

```
call "C:\wdk\1709\BuildEnv\SetupBuildEnv.cmd"
msbuild [YourSolution].sln /t:rebuild /m /p:configuration=Release/p:platform=x64 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /clp:ErrorsAndSummary
```

To use SDV after completing a build:

```
call "C:\wdk\1709\BuildEnv\SetupBuildEnv.cmd"
msbuild /t:sdv /p:Inputs="/check:*" [YourProject].vcxproj /p:configuration=release /p:platform=x64
```

Comment: This only tells me how to invoke MSBuild (which is covered extensively in the documentation), not how to generate the files that MSBuild needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The EWDK provides everything you need to build drivers. What generated files are you referring to?